# Elasticsearch one big cluster VS tribe node?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Problem descriptions:
- Multiple machines producing logs.
- On each machine we have logstash which filters the log files and sends them to a local elasticsearch
- We would like to keep the machines as separate as possible and avoid intercommunication
- But we would also like to be able to visualize all of these logs with a single Kibana instance

Approaches:

1. Make each machine a single node ES cluster, and have one of the machines as a tribe node with Kibana installed on this machine (of course with avoiding indices conflict)
2. Make all machines (nodes) part of a single cluster with each node writing to unique index of one shard and statically map each shard to its node, and finally of course having one instance of kibana for the cluster

Question:
Which approach is more appropriate for the described scenario in terms of: limiting inter machine communications, cluster management, and maybe other aspects that I haven't think about ?

Answer (score 0):

Tribe node is there because of this requirements. So my advice to use the Tribe node setup.

With the second option;

- There will be a cluster but you will not use its benefits (replica shards, shard relocation, query performance, etc)
- Benefits mentioned above will be pain points that will generate configuration complexity and troubleshooting hell.
- Besides the shard allocation and node communication there will be other things to configure that nodes will have when they are in a cluster.